# A property of subsequences of complex numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of complex numbers such that $|x_n|\geq 1-\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$.

If $\{x_{n_k}\}$ is a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$. Is it true that 
$$|x_{n_k}|\geq 1-\frac{1}{k},$$
 for all $k$.

Comment: Hint: the numbers being complex is a red herring; nothing about them is used except their magnitude...

Comment: Also note that $n_k \ge k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $n_k \geq k$ for all $k$. So, $-1/k \leq -1/n_k$ for all $k$. This implies that,

$1-1/k \leq 1-1/n_k \leq |x_{n_k}|$ for all $k$.

Comment: Yeah. Fixed it.